# web scraping python <span> with id

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrap data in the `<span/>` attribute for a given website using BeautifulSoup. You can see at the screenshot where it locates. However, the code that I'm using is just returning an empty list. I can't find the data in the list that I want. What am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url = "http://144.122.167.229"
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
data = opener.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

your_data = list()

for line in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'id': 'mc1_legend_value'}):
    your_data.append(line.text)

for line in soup.findAll('span'):
    your_data.append(line.text)
```

ScreenShot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MDIl.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: Can you find the `<span>` tag in page source?

Comment: There is no <span> tag that i want in page source. I can see them Elements tab in chrome

Comment: That's the reason you get empty list. Your `data` only contains the page source code of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashboard from the screenshot looks to me like something javascript would generate. If you can't find the  tag in the page source, that means it was later added by some javascript code or your browser tried to fix some html which it considered broken or out of place.

Keep in mind that right now you're sending a request to a server and it serves you the plain html back. A browser would parse the html and execute any javascript code if it finds any. In your case, beautiful soup or urllib doesn't execute any javascript code. urllib fetches the html and beautiful soup makes it easier to parse and extract relevant information.

If you want to get the value from that  tag, I recommend using a headless browser to render your page and just after that parse it's html through beautiful soup or any other parser.

Give a try to selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.
You can control your own browser programmatically. You can make it request the page for you, render it, save the new html in a variable, parse it using beautifoul soup and extract the values you're interested in. I believe that it already has it's own parser implemented which you can use directly to search for that  tag.
Or maybe even scrapinghub's splash: https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

If the dashboard communicates with a server in real-time and that value is continuously received from the server, you could take a look at what requests are sent to the server in order to get that value. Take a look in developer console under the networks tab. Press F12 to open the developer console and click on `Network`. Refresh the page and you should get all the request send to the server along with the responses. Requests sent by the javascript are usually XMLHttpRequests. Click on `XHR` in the `Network` tab to filter out any other requests. (These are instructions for Google Chrome. Firefox might differ a bit).